# BlackBerry: setting the height of a field manager without manually building the layout

Tags: blackberry

I want to set the height of a manager so that my tab bar sits perfectly beneath the manager at the bottom of the screen.

I'd add my vertical field manager which holds all the content, then I add(tabbar).

The problem is that when I use the following, all the fields disappear. However, the height is set the way I want it.

```c
bottom_vfm = new VerticalFieldManager() {       
    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        setExtent(maxWidth, 200);
    }
};
```

Do I have to manually setChildPosition and layoutChild for every field? Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u tried like this?

```
bottom_vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(){


        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight){

                super.sublayout(maxWidth,200);
                setExtent(maxWidth,200);
        }
    };
```